# Overriding Components Styles w/ Global Stylesheet

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2

The project uses a `main.scss` that is imported to in the `main.js` file. From there I will add styling to each component, within their respective `vue` files.

I am wondering if I could have a global stylesheet that would be injected *after* the component styles. The styles positioning in the `head` would look something like: `main.scss -> component stylings -> overrides.scss`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so that importing scss file inside `bootstrap.js` is a good idea.
You can create one `main.scss` file in `/src/scss/` and inside that file put something down like that:

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
@import 'global/bootstrap/your_component';

@import 'helpers/overrides';
```

and depends of your needs change the path name.

Be sure that your file is imported in `src/main.js` by adding line:

```
import 'styles/main.scss';
```

This directory structure will be able to do some updates in the way like you want and will be easy to read and understand where the files are.

Comment: are you saying I should `@import` from `main.js` instead of `bootstrap.js`? `main.js` already has `require('./bootstrap');`... I am a little lost on `@import 'global/bootstrap/your_component';` as well, we don't have a `bootstrap` directory just the `js` file - as you can tell I am a little lost here and new to Vue

Comment: I meant: import `bootstrap.js` in `main.js` + import `main.scss` which contains bootstrap styles (scss) and your scss files. By the way: have you tried use Bootstrap Vue? [link](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/) Using   Bootstrap with jQuery might be a little bit inappropriate.

Comment: Oh this doesn't have anything to do with twitter bootstrap; the `bootstrap.js` is the bootstrap file to configure the vue app code - the dev just decided to call it bootstrap (confusing I know)

Comment: I still don't understand what a problem you have. I gave you a structure what you can use to override your bootstrap or custom components styling. Try google it: `scss project structure` to better understand how it works.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestions but that is not what I was asking. I was asking how to overide **component styling**. This isn't a question about `scss`, it's specific to `vue`/webpack. In vue all component styling, in `<style>` tags get loaded last and I want to know if there is a way to change that.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare CSS follow specificity. The rule in `overrides.scss` has the highest priority and in `main.scss` has lower. The rule in `main.scss` and component can have the same priority, but the rule in the component is declared later, so it will be applied to the element.

You can read more about this behaviour in: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: While this is a viable workaround, it is not what I am looking for. Thank you for the suggestion.